# Maple: Compiling function that substitutes numbers into expression

Tags: optimization, maple

I have a complex Maple expression which is in this form:

```
expr := Sum(f(x, t, n), n=1...N);
```

To numerically evaluate this in Maple for any `x` and `t`, I might write

```
result := (x_, t_) -> value(subs(x=x_, t=t_, N=1000, expr));
result(0.5, 2.0); # some number
```

However, especially for large `N`, this computation is very expensive. How can I speed up `result(x, t)`?

I have tried using `Compiler:-Compile`, but the functions `subs` and `value` have no analogue in C code, so this fails. (`Compiler:-Compile(result);` gives an error message: `Warning, the function names {subs, value} are not recognized in the target language`.)

How can I transform `result` so that it may be compiled and evaluated faster, without having to manually rewrite the `Sum` as for-loop inside a procedure? I can’t reimplement it from scratch because `expr` is generated symbolically and I don’t want to lose generality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping the actual call of procedure `result` below within a call to `evalf` we instruct Maple to try its `evalf/Sum` technique of numeric summation convergence acceleration (via Levin-u transformation). This is quick in the case that the trailing terms' contribution is estimated as dropping off quick "enough".

```
restart;

# for an example
f := (x,t,n)->sin((x-t)/n*Pi):

expr := Sum(f(x, t, n), n=1...N):

result1 := unapply( expr, [x,t,N] ):

evalf(result1( 2.0, 0.1, 10000 ));
                      46.91622734
```

The procedure `result2` below uses `add` instead of `sum`.  Your original approach of applying the `value` command to the inert `Sum` would produce an active `sum` call, which -- on every invocation, and for each set of passed arguments -- would likely end up causing slow and unnecessary, unsuccessful attempts at symbolic summation *before* falling back to merely adding up the terms numerically.

By simply replacing the inert `Sum` with the much more appropriate `add` command we can bypass all such repeated, failing, and wasted attempts at symbolic summation and go straight to the job of numerically adding up all the terms.

```
result2 := unapply( subs(Sum=add,expr), [x::float,t::float,N::integer] ):

result2( 2.0, 0.1, 10000 );
                      46.91622733
```

If the expression `expr` is evalhf'able then (since `add` is too) we can instead do the numerical adding of all the terms under Maple's faster double-precision floating-point evaluation mechanism.

```
evalhf(result1( 2.0, 0.1, 10000 ));
                  46.9162273272279222
```